# Replace string character with an image

Tags: ios, objective-c, replace, emoji

I am working on emoji in chat app. When someone send me emoji, i received message in this format :-  Hello...(worried) how are you(happy)?

> (worried) and (happy) are considerd as emoji

```
arremojivalue=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"(worried)",@"(sad)",@"(bandit)",@"(wink)",@"(surprised)",@"(smirking)",@"(laugh)",@"(cool)",@"(stoned)",@"(smile)",@"(nerd)",@"(happy)",@"(evil-grin)",@"(tongue)",@"(lips-sealed)",@"(GIF)",@"(dull)", nil];
```

When I received message(string) how can i check it contains the word above from arremojivalue. I want to replace that (worried) and (happy) word from message string to 'emoji'.

I have tried this one:-

```
NSString *stremoji;
stremoji=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",arremojivalue];

if ([message containsString:stremoji])
{
     message= [message stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:stremoji
                                                    withString:@"(emoji)"];

     cell.textLabel.text=message; //@"Emoji arrived";
}
```

**First of all please give me answer how can i remove those words(worried)(happy) from string to 'emoji'.**

**After that i want to replace those 'emoji' words to UIWebview to display GIF emoji.**

Thanks

Comment: I'd say `NSAttributedString`, with `NSTextAttachment`. But I'm not sure that .gif are easy to render.

Comment: would using an emoji font be appropriate in your situation? or simply using the unicode values for your emojis.

Comment: @myte I am not using unicode values for emojis.

Comment: @bhavin ramani i wasn't asking if you were.  i was suggesting that perhaps it might be an option to do so depending on your exact circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this

```
NSArray *arremojivalue=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"(worried)",@"(sad)",@"(bandit)",@"(wink)",@"(surprised)",@"(smirking)",@"(laugh)",@"(cool)",@"(stoned)",@"(smile)",@"(nerd)",@"(happy)",@"(evil-grin)",@"(tongue)",@"(lips-sealed)",@"(GIF)",@"(dull)", nil];

//
NSString *message = @"Hello...(worried) how are you(happy)?";

for (NSString *emoji in arremojivalue) {
    if ([message containsString:emoji]){
       message = [message stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:emoji withString:YourEmojiValue];//value for (worried) = @":)"
    }
}
 NSLog(@"message updated:%@",message);
```

//2nd part of your question

```
NSDictionary *emojiDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 @":)",@"(worried)",
                                 @"(:D)",@"(smile)",
                                 nil];
NSString *message = @"Hello...(worried) how are you(smile)?";

for (NSString *emojiKey in emojiDictionary.allKeys) {
    if ([message containsString:emojiKey]){
        message = [message stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:emojiKey withString:[emojiDictionary valueForKey:emojiKey]];
    }
}
 NSLog(@"message updated:%@",message);
```

Comment: Thanks @jamil65able this solved my problem. but can i display that gif image from array which i have received.

Comment: I want to display webview in label for emoji where i have (worried) and (happy) word in string.

Comment: Yes Thanks...this is working like charm but how can i take webview instead of ":-)" .

Answer (score 0):

This is an ideal situation to replace using regular expressions.

```
NSArray *emojiList = @[@"(sad)",@"(happy)",@"(angry)"] // and so on ..

NSString *regex = [emojiList componentsJoinedByString:@" | "];
regex = [string stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"(" withString:@"\\("];

regex = [string stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@")" withString:@"\\)"];

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regex options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];

NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@"(emoji)"];
```